# Google Apps Script Documentation: Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id

Tags: google-apps-script, exception, charts, documentation

is there a place where I can get the documentation on google apps script, besides what is available on googles' developer website?

what I am looking for is the source code for the exceptions that get thrown. I want to understand the functions that are throwing the errors, so as to help me debug.

because honestly some of the documentation is good, but the deeper you go the worse the documentation gets. I cannot find answers to the exceptions (that seem random)

Also any clue as to why this error keeps popping up will be appreciated.
My code attempts to insertChart.

If I manually create empty chart and use the same code with updatechart, it works perfectly fine.
Also insertChart works fine if I run it on a different spreadsheet. (same code) just changing the destination

```
function myFunction() {
  let poster;
  let sheet = getSheet(test_status);
  let sheet_name = sheet.getSheetName();
  

  if (test_status == true){
    poster = sheet;
  } 
  else if (test_status == false){
    poster = live;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < machine.length; i++){
    let end = variables.getRange(8, machine[i][1]).getValue();
    let max = sheet.getRange(end, 13).getValue();
    let gridlines = sheet.getRange(end, 12).getValue()+1;
    let rangeOne = sheet.getRange("H"+end);
    let rangeTwo = sheet.getRange("O"+end);
    let value = variables.getRange(9, machine[i][1]).getValue();

    // var chart = poster.getCharts()[i+3];
    // ranges = chart.getRanges();

    let chart = poster.newChart()
    //chart = chart.modify()
      .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
      .setPosition(48, value, 1, 1)
      .setOption('title', machine[i][0])
      .setOption('titleTextStyle',{fontSize : 30, color : 'black', bold : true})
      .setOption('subtitle', sheet_name)
      .setOption('subtitleTextStyle',{fontSize : 24, color : 'grey', bold : true})
      .setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", false)
      .setOption("width", 724)
      .setOption("height", 392)
      .setOption("is3D", true)

      .addRange(rangeTwo)
      .addRange(rangeOne)

      .setOption("addRange", rangeOne)
      .setOption("hAxis",{minValue: 0})
      .setOption("hAxis",{maxValue: max})
      .setOption("hAxis",{gridlines: { count: gridlines}})
      .setOption("hAxis",{minorGridlines: { count: 1}})
      .setOption("hAxis", {textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 16}})
      
      .setOption("series", {0 : {dataLabel: "value"}}) 
      .setOption("series", {1 : {dataLabel: "value"}})
      .setOption("series", {0 :{labelInLegend: "Goal"}})
      .setOption("series", {1 :{labelInLegend: "Actual Progress"}})
      .setOption("series", {0 :{color: 'blue'}, 1: {color: 'green'}})
      .setOption("legend", {textStyle : {fontSize: 24}}) //works
      .setOption("series", {0: {annotations: {textStyle : {fontSize : 24, color : 'white'}}}})
      .setOption("series", {1: {annotations: {textStyle : {fontSize : 24, color : 'white'}}}})
      
    .build();

    Logger.log(chart);
    poster.insertChart(chart);
    //poster.updateChart(chart);
  }}
```

Comment: Can you share a copy of the sheet that shows the problem scenario?

Comment: Hello @Youstina - About the same time as you posted that question, my users started experiencing the same issue - I'm not sure it's actually related to your script - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187573915 - Check this tickt I just opened - If the desciption seems right - You should confirm you have the same problem on that ticket